# Find files using gnu parallel

Tags: shell, find, gnu-parallel

I understand that using the following command

```
find . -name "*.foo" | parallel grep bar
```

will be executed in 2 steps :

1) do a search for all files matching "*.foo" .

2) Then on this set of files it will do a parallel search to look for index "bar" inside the files .

But is it also possible to parallellize the first step itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really think your disks are up to parallel finding and grepping, you could do this:

```
printf "%s\0" */ | parallel -0 'find {} -name "*foo" | parallel grep bar'
```

Running a full `grep` process for each file is also not very sensible. You should consider using **GNU Parallel**'s `-X` option to let each `grep` process search multiple files.

Comment: @AbhishekJain Questions and answers are free. Please just ask a new question and you will likely get a better quality answer than from tacking it on the end of another one as more people will see it. By all means add a link back to here for reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**BLUF:** pipe `|` is used to run the command on the output of previous command.

Here the out of find is list of files, and grep can work in parallel on each file. 
if you reverse the order then output of grep is list of lines containing your string. and find wont work on that output.

You can do this in single command:

```
grep -R --include="foo*" "bar" /path/to/directory
```

- -R means recursive, so it will go into subdirectories of the directory you're grepping through
- --include="*.c" means "look for files ending in .c"
- "bar" is the pattern you're grepping for
- /path/to/directory is the path to the directory you want to grep through

Comment: Yeah I understand that. But is there a replacement for find command that would do the first query also in parallel i.e look for string "*.foo" in multiple filenames at the same time ?

Comment: if foo* types of file are in the same directory then `grep -rn -l "bar"` would work